# why is bootstrap carousel not adhering to my image size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is my code for my carousel i am attempting to create with bootstrap & html.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="width: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="download.jpg"
      alt="" width="250" height="250">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
         <h4>First Thumbnail label</h4>

        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id
          elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies
          vehicula ut id elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="download3.jpg"
      alt="" width="250" height="250">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
         <h4>Second Thumbnail label</h4>

        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id
          elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies
          vehicula ut id elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="download.jpg"
      alt="" width="250" height="250">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
         <h4>Third Thumbnail label</h4>

        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id
          elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies
          vehicula ut id elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

  <a
  class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div>
```

for some reasons the images on the carousel change size and the carousel collapses in size when coming across one particular image?

how can this be prevented?

Comment: Can you post a link/JSFiddle so we can also see any other CSS or JS you are using? Have you used a DTD?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y53yL5ya/ Here is a Fiddle... as you can see it's incomplete. Please add enough code to it to reproduce your problem so that we can see the issue ourselves, BlackMagma